# What exactly means <> in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am new in C#, going from PHP. Everything is almost clear, except I don't know what exactly means construction Interface/Collection **<>**.

I am already using the <> for "type definition", but what it means exactly. I am using it like this:

```
class TaskComparer : IEqualityComparer<Task> ...
class TaskQueue : ConcurrentQueue<Task> ...
```

etc. Did you see any article about this? Please post a link. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "construction Interface/Collection `<>`"? Can you be a bit more specific, post an example code?

Comment: I have written it into question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called "Generics", and it's a way to (as you say) define a type parameter.  Here's an introductory article on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx

As a simple example of the utility of this, think about a Repository pattern.

```
public interface IRepository<T> {
    public void Add (T obj);
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}
```

With the correct implementation, now you can have a repository interface for any type of entity.

```
public void someMethod(IRepository<Person> personsRepo) 
{
    IEnumerable<Person> persons = personsRepo.GetAll();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You most probably mean [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The

*identifier* `<` *type definition* `>`

block after an identifier denotes a type constructed from a [*generic type definition*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

This This definition is *recursive*: you can have generic types constructed from other generic types: in the same way that you can have arrays of arrays, you can construct lists of lists, lists of dictionaries, and so on.

In addition, you can build generic functions using similar constructs, except instead of the type or the interface name you put a name of a generic function.

You can build your own generic type and function definitions, and access them both directly or through reflection. The concept is very powerful, because it expands strong typing to types built from other types.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a collection, it defines which type of data will be inside of the collection. It is just a way to improfe type security. A little example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();

test.Add(1); // will work
test.Add("2");  //will throw an exception, String cannot be cast to int
```

Comment: That's a Java example, and the final line wouldn't throw an exception - it would fail to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Do read the articles about generics provided by the others; still, I'm giving you a quick introduction here.

Say, we want to write an id function (returning exactly it's input). This should be working for every type, right? So, our naive approach is using `object`:

```
object id(object x) {
    return x
}
```

However, this returns an `object` every time -- you have to convert afterwards to get back your "concrete" type, like so: `int x = (int)id(12)`. Generics solve this issue. They allow you to parametrize the type to keep it *exactly the same*:

```
T id2<T> (T x) {
    return x
}
```

Looking at the type signature, you can see that this version takes *any* `T` and returns *the same* `T` (replace `T` with `int`, and you'll see).

I hope that gives you a quick overview. Also, do read about constraints.